# Changing of tags in Tag based push notification in MFP

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I had implemented tag based push notification for my app with say 100 tags. Now there is a requirement to remove few tags and add few new tags. The problem I am facing is that a lot of devices are already subscribed to these tags. When I will add and remove new tags, Do I need to clear all previously subscribed tags and start a fresh subscription process. In case if I have to remove, Is there a simple way to delete all subscription or Do I have to clear all devices one by one from worklightconsole?

Comment: What is your IBM MobileFirst version?

Comment: @IdanAdar I am using MFP 7.0. I wrote an api to fetch all devices and delete them one by one. So the task is done. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please either delete this question or write this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the user wrote in the comments:

> I wrote an api to fetch all devices and delete them one by one. So the task is done. Thanks for help.